# Android FPS, how to make it smoother?

Tags: android, loops, frame-rate, smoothing

I am having trouble in constructing a basic game loop for my game. I am at the early phase and all I want to do is to move the the ball at a constant speed (for ex: 3) through the bottom of the screen. The position of the ball is updated in the main panel update method and it is drawed in the render part as expected. Nothing exceptional in the mechanism. The ball moves but it is definitely not smooth, the visual is quiet disturbing.. I measured the implementation times of these methods and the total implementation time of this couple is about 3-4 milliseconds. Under these circumstances, what is the suitable FPS? Are the given constant values suitable What is missing or wrong in my mechanism? Thanks a lot in advance. the code block in main thread.

```
private final static int MAX_FPS = 200;
private final static int FRAME_PERIOD = 1000 / MAX_FPS;
private final static int    MAX_FRAME_SKIPS = 5;

public void run() {

    initTimingElements();
    long beginTime;
    long timeDiff;
    int sleepTime;
    int framesSkipped;
    long beginTime2;

    long diff1;
    long diff2;

    sleepTime = 0;

    Canvas canvas;
    Log.d(TAG, "Starting game loop");
    while (running) {
        canvas = null;
        try {
            canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
            synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                beginTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                framesSkipped = 0; 

                this.gamePanel.update();
                diff1=System.currentTimeMillis()-beginTime;
                beginTime2=System.currentTimeMillis();
                this.gamePanel.render(canvas);
                diff2=System.currentTimeMillis()-beginTime2;



                timeDiff = System.currentTimeMillis() - beginTime;
                sleepTime = (int) (FRAME_PERIOD - timeDiff);

                if (sleepTime > 0) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }                   
                while (sleepTime < 0 && framesSkipped < MAX_FRAME_SKIPS) {
                    this.gamePanel.update();
                    sleepTime += FRAME_PERIOD;
                    framesSkipped++;
                }
                if (framesSkipped > 0) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Skipped:" + framesSkipped);
                }
                framesSkippedPerStatCycle += framesSkipped;
                storeStats();
            }
        } finally {
            if (canvas != null) {
                surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wJYTBjMZJh0) video (around the 34:07 mark) I don't do any animations myself but this might apply to your situation.

Answer (score -1):

Try using a TimerTask that fires off every 60ms or so.
That's what I do until I stop being lazy enough to do a proper implementation, but it works well.
Just remember that run() will be executed in a different thread, so use runOnUIThread() to run whatever code you need.

Comment: I could not get it buddy, the game mechanism is handled by another thread's run method, using the UI thread's run method blocks the mechanism?? can you explain your answer with a simple algorithm??

Comment: Well, you'll have to fiddle a lot to get it.  Get rid of your sleep call, also STRICTLY handle game logic in another thread, and do drawing in the usual UI thread, drawing as fast as possible.  There are several issues: decouple drawing from logic, calculate logic every 60fps and draw as fast as possible or when the scene has changed.  Lock your scene and maybe use a buffer to continue drawing while the logic thread is going.  Good luck